# c# properties, have a get with an auto-implemmented private set

Tags: c#, properties, field, automatic-properties

Using c# auto-implemented properties can I have a class that does the following (psuedo C# code because I get an error - which is below when trying to compile this):

```
public class Foo {
    public String HouseName { get; private set; }
    public int HouseId { get; private set; }
    public int BedsTotal { 
        get { return (BedsTotal < 0) ? 0 : BedsTotal; }
        private set;
    }
}
```

Error   5   'House.BedsTotal.set' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial c:\src\House.cs

To me it seems like I should be able to get a body for the getter and rely on the private set being auto-generated like it would be if I did a { get; private set; } but that's not working.

Do I need to go the whole way and set up member variables, take the private setter off, and use the members vars instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to set up private variables because at the moment you will end up in a loop trying to read the `get {}` portion because it references itself.

Set up a private backing variable like this:

```
private int _bedsTotal;
public int BedsTotal { 
        get { return (_bedsTotal < 0) ? 0 : _bedsTotal; }
        private set { _bedsTotal = value; }
    }
```

Then you can access beds through the private setter

Comment: Rather than a method, he can use a private setter, like `private set {  _bedsTotal = value; }`

Answer (score 2):

i whould go for an even more easier approach

```
private int _bedsTotal;
public int BedsTotal
{ 
    get
    {
        return (this._bedsTotal < 0) ? 0 : this._bedsTotal;
    }
    private set
    {
        this._bedsTotal = value;
    }
}
```

and so you can set the value of `BedsTotal` like this : `this.BedsTotal = [integer];`, no need to used other private methods since you can make use of the `set`

Comment: This will allow other classes to set the value of `_bedsTotal`. OP wants to make the setter private

Comment: yeah my bad, forgot the `private` term

Comment: Other classes see neither the setter nor the _bedsTotal member since they are both declared private. They are only allowed to use the getter

EDIT: I already saw the updated version ;)